# React won't render within map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I'm trying to render an array containing some objects using the JS function map().
However when I return the text nothing is shown:

```
console.log(this.props.project.projects); // (2) [{…}, {…}]
  this.props.project.projects.map((item, index) => {
    console.log(item.projectDescription); //"Testproject"
    return (
        <div key={index}>
         {item.projectDescription}
        </div>
      )
  })
```

I just don't get it, why there is no text shown, since the console.log(item.projectDescription) shows exactly what I want to display.

**Update:**
It works when I change it to this:

```
return this.props.project.projects.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index} style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
         {item.projektBeschreibung}
        </div>
      ))
```

I already thought about using the foreach-method but I think it should actually work using the map()-function.

Here you can see also the render method of my Component.

```
class ProjectRow extends Component {

  renderProjects() {
    console.log(this.props.project);
    if (this.props.project.loading) {
    return (
      <div style={{color: '#fff'}}>
        Loading
      </div>
    )
    } else {
      console.log(this.props.project.projects);
      this.props.project.projects.map((item, index) => {
        console.log(item);
        console.log(item.projektBeschreibung);
        console.log(index);
        return (
            <div key={index}>
             {item.projektBeschreibung}
            </div>
          )
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderProjects()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In your first example, I think you just need to wrap the children with a parent element. Something like `<div>{children}</div>` should work.

Comment: did you show the code exactly as in the render function? you may not be displaying or returning whatever function is running the map

Comment: The map function returns a new array. It doesn't change the existing one. You must set a variable to the mapped array and render that variable.

Comment: [It works fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/j2rn5wa6/2/) using your code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `renderProjects` function is not returning anything when it hits your else case. Here is an example of use:

```
renderProjects() {
  console.log(this.props.project);

  if (this.props.project.loading) {
    return (
      <div style={{color: '#fff'}}>
        Loading
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    console.log(this.props.project.projects);

    // added return statement here
    return this.props.project.projects.map((item, index) => {
      console.log(item);
      console.log(item.projektBeschreibung);
      console.log(index);
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          {item.projektBeschreibung}
        </div>
      )
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually it works when I use your second example. Actually I'm not sure why my approach didn't work because I thought I was returning it aswell.

Answer (score -1):

why not use map like below ?

```
render(){
  return(
    <div>
     {this.props.project.projects.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>         
             {item.projectDescription}
        </div>
      ))}
  </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: Should the `map` call be wrapped in `{ ... }` for this to work?

Comment: @charlietfl he said nothing was rendered , but here is not just shorten syntax , is return project description text in div